# "Apposition," "Metonymy," & Synecodche

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What's the difference between, apposition, metonymy, and synecdoche? May apposition include metonymy or synecdoche?

Comment: _Apposition_ is a grammatical term -- it indicates the grammatical relation between two nouns or noun phrases, like _my son, the musician_. Normally it indicates that the two refer to the same individual. The other two aren't grammatical. _Synecdoche_ is a type of metonymy; it's a term mostly valuable because almost nobody knows what it mean,s but it sounds very Greek and therefore is impressive. _Metonymy_ is a variety of metaphoric reference in which a part of a thing is used to symbolize the whole.

Comment: So the distinction is that "apposition" is a "grammatical term" while metonymy and synecdoche are metaphors and tools for interpretation. But, they're all similar in function. Metonymy is putting one word or thing for another & Synecdoche uses a part for the whole, while Apposition are simply two nouns referring to each other in that one explains the other. Therefore, it seems all 3 function similarly where one noun is used to explain or identify another noun. Would that be correct?

Comment: No, there's no "in that one explains the other" with apposition. What it gets used for is irrelevant. On the other hand, metonymy (nobody uses _synecdoche_ to mean anything; don't bother with it) doesn't depend on how it's done -- it could be apposition, but it could be a relative clause or an adverb or a noun complement. How it's done is irrelevant. It's like comparing a red car to a getaway car -- they're not the same kind of "car" and so they don't compare.

Answer (score 1):

These three words are very simple to understand. Addressing your sub-question: `May apposition include metonymy or synecdoche?` **No**, *apposition* does not include *metonymy* or *synecdoche*.  In fact, *apposition* is a **grammatical construct**, whereas, *metonymy* and *synecdoche* are **figure of speech**.

[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-syn1.htm) has lucid explanation on metonymy and synecdoche.

> Both<sup>1</sup> are figures of speech used in rhetoric. They’re not the same thing, though metonymy is often interpreted so widely that synecdoche can be regarded as a special case of it.

Explanation about **Synecdoche**:

> Let’s take synecdoche first. You use this when you speak of a part of something but mean the whole thing. When Patrick O’Brian has Captain Jack Aubrey tell his first lieutenant to “let the hands go to dinner” he’s employing synecdoche, because he’s using a part (the hand) for the whole man. You can also reverse the whole and the part, so using a word for something when you only mean part of it. This often comes up in sport: a commentator might say that “The West Indies has lost to England” when he means that the West Indian team has lost to the English one. America is often used as synecdoche in this second sense, as the word refers to the whole continent but is frequently applied to a part of it, the USA.

Further example,

Example: "I have ***four mouths*** to feed at home."

It simply means, "I have ***four family members*** to feed at home."

Here,

*Mouths* (the part) is used to represent *people* (the whole thing).

Explanation about **Metonymy**:

> Metonymy is similar, but uses something more generally or loosely associated with a concept to stand in for it. When Americans speak of the Oval Office, for example, they are really referring to the activity within it, the position or function of the President. It’s a linked term, and so a metonym. British writers refer similarly to the Crown, when they’re really discussing the powers, authority and responsibilities of the monarchy, which is symbolized by the crown. The difference between synecdoche and metonymy is that in metonymy the word you employ is linked to the concept you are really talking about, but isn't actually a part of it. Another example is the turf for horse racing. But the distinction isn't always obvious and often can’t be rigorously applied, and many people use metonymy to mean both.

Example: "The White House declared that we are at war with Mars."

Here,

The ***White House*** is a metonymy for the ***President of the United States***.

Explanation about **Apposition** by [Dartmouth Uni.](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~milton/reading_room/rhetoric/text.shtml)

> Placing side by side two coordinate elements, the second of which serves as an explanation or modification of the first

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/apposition):
When you put two things right next to each other, you can call that apposition. The apposition of your dog and your cat makes an adorable photograph.

A grammatical relation between a word and a noun phrase that follows. Though you can use the noun apposition to talk about the positioning of objects — or words — close together, it's usually found in scientific or technical writing. In grammar, an apposition occurs when two words or phrases are placed beside each other in a sentence so that one describes or defines the other.

An example is the phrase "**my dog** ***Woofers***," in which "**my dog**" is in apposition to the name "***Woofers***." "My dog" and "Woofers" are placed side by side and represent same pet.

So, what is the difference between Apposition and Metonymy/Synecdoche?

-> Apposition is used literally and Metonymy/Synecdoche are used figuratively. In apposition, you have two nouns or noun phrases side by side. In which, second noun/noun-phrase describes the first noun/noun-phrase.

-> Whereas, in metonymy/synecdoche there is only one noun in sentence presenting other noun figuratively. We need to understood other noun figuratively, it is not present in the given sentence.

I hope these explanation help!

---

<sub>1.Metonymy and synecdoche</sub>

Comment: Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Doug you can accept the answer, if you are satisfied with it.